# How do I obtain a view from fragment A with the fragment listener pattern?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Once something is clicked in fragment B, I want to pass a string from it to the previous fragment, fragment A.

I tried to accomplish this by creating a listener interface within fragment B that the containing activity implements.  In fragment B's onAttach, I cast the activity to the listener type. When something is clicked in fragment B, I invoke the listener's callback that must be defined in the Activity:

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
selectedListener.onItemSelected(dataItem);
}
```

});

In the activity:

```
@Override public void onItemSelected(MyData dataItem) {
    FragmentA currentFragment = (FragmentA)fragMgr.findFragmentByTag("FragmentA");
    LinearLayout containerView = currentFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.container);
```

At this point the fragment backstack looks like fragmentA-->fragmentB.  Calling fragmentA's getView in the callback returns null, why is this and how can I obtain this view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getView()` is probably returning null because you are trying to access it before the fragment's `onCreateView()` has been called.

Try just setting the data on a field of the fragment (i.e. `currentFragment.setMyData(dataItem)`), then checking for a non-null value for that field in `onCreateView()`.